# Partitioning Windows 8.1 in order to have data partition first and system partitions at HDD end

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, gparted

How can I have recovery partition at the HDD end? My aim is to have data partition installed on fastest sectors of my hard drive, as I don't really care if restoring operations are slow...

During Windows installation, when I create a partition, I get immediately created EFI and recovery ones just before the actual data partition. EFI position is good, I want my PC boot fast, but I **want** to move partitions I don't care about speed. I've also considered GParted, but I think I'm not able to use it :P

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  These partitions are at the start of the disk for reasons other then speed.

Comment: I didn't know it. Could you explain what are the reasons?

Comment: For one its part of the GPT standard that the EFI partition will be in a certain location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ramhound points out in his comment, they're not located where they are for speed; it's so the system knows where to find the partitions while at the BIOS/EFI/Pre-OS level.

Regardless, just because a partition appears in front/ahead of another doesn't mean it's physically located in that order on the disk.

Also, you probably wouldn't even notice the difference even if you DID manage to reorder them like that.

Basically, if you want a faster HDD access, get a faster HDD (or better, an SSD).

And of course you can use GPartEd, just boot form a LiveCD; but be aware you may not have a working file system when you're done, so make backups first.